# Additional 'noisy' pixel are added when setfill

Tags: kineticjs

I have followed this example: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-modify-shape-color-on-click/ in order to change color of my shape on mouse actions.

All is ok about setting the color but see the example :

i have a blue line. When I translate it to red, some blue pixels remain on the borders of the line. And when i come back to blue, thn some red pixels remain.

my code is the following:

```
recolor: function(newColor){
    // Children are Kinetic.rect or Kinetic.line
    var children=this.group.children;

    for( var k in children){

        if(children[k] instanceof Kinetic.Line)
            children[k].setStroke(newColor);
        else
            children[k].setFill(newColor);
    }
    this.group.draw();
}
```

Here is a screenshot (normal and zoomed):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: have you tried this in different browsers?

Comment: Yes, Chromium and firefox. Each up to date

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know what is happening that would make such an error, you can try this:

```
recolor: function(newColor){
    // Children are Kinetic.rect or Kinetic.line
    var children=this.group.children;

    for( var k in children){

        if(children[k] instanceof Kinetic.Line)
            children[k] = children[k].clone({stroke: newColor});
        else
            children[k] = children[k].clone({fill: newColor});
    }
    this.group.draw();
    this.group.getLayer().draw();
}
```

this just clones your objects and replaces them with ones that have a single change in config. If this doesn't fix your problem, then it is not a problem with kineticJS.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem. But i found the cause of the problem. If I call layer.draw()   instead of group.draw()  noise goes away. I tryed with other non dynamic example. Problem still occurs. I will repport the bug.